# How to create a google site page that will not let you see the google website until a secret password is answered?

Tags: passwords, block, html, google-sites

Is it possible to create a google sites page that has an initial page with a password box. Once the password has been submitted via that page and it is confirmed to be correct, the rest of the site will open?

How would one go about this ?

Thanks in advance,

Happy Holidays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google sites has an ACL where you can share the site with any user that has a Google ID. Users that want to use another id can [link](https://accounts.google.com/NewAccount?hl=en) any email address to a Google id.

With a lot of app script you could create your own authentication scheme, but why would you want to do that? I cannot think of any use case that would worth it to build your own authentication scheme.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I appreciate the help. I will try your method and see if this works.